# Is a question about TENS units on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

A friend of mine has gotten a recommendation to get a TENS unit for his nape (back of his neck). Neither of us has had experience with these, and I was thinking I might ask about how to evaluate the large number of available devices for safety and perhaps efficacy - as, after all, it's a device which electrocutes you a little.

Would such a question be on topic?

I am *not* asking for specific product recommendations.

Comment: Absolutely. As long as the question is about the efficacy and usage guidelines, and not specific to an individual treatment you should be fine. We have had TENS unit questions before on the site that have done well.

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead and ask what studies exist to support TENS, what the outcome is etc. I think those are perfectly reasonable questions and on-topic.

Comment: That would be a different question than the one I intend to ask...

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Unfortunately, the question you asked doesn't fit the site. The guidance offered by JohnP and Narusan was spot on.